What should these PUA characters look like?
I stumbled upon this page.  (I think it's in Hokkien?) Some of the characters are in the Unicode Private Use Area (PUA).  My browser displays some of them, but others are missing. I'd like to know:

Are the characters I see in my browser actually the correct ones? Looking at the Romanization, I suspect this is very wrong. Do I need a different font?
Where are these characters defined? I looked at the table for BabelStone Han PUA, but it doesn't seem to be the right one.

Here is the title, repeated as the first line of the text:

Lê– bîng – kok – sió hó miâ – siann
（5-5）黎明國小好名聲

And here is what I see in my web browser:

As you can see, all the PUA characters are missing in the font used in the heading, but half of them show up in the text itself.
The actual Unicode code points are:

U+9ECE 黎
U+E961 
U+660E 明
U+E378 
U+570B 國
U+EF61 
U+5C0F 小
U+EC63 
U+597D 好
U+E6A0 
U+540D 名
U+EA07 
U+8072 聲
U+EC3B 


These are almost definitely supposed to be a variety of Taiwanese Hokkien phonetic symbols. You can verify this by comparing the code points of the PUA characters which are supposed to sound the same (e.g. the character after 名) in the entire poem. I couldn't find anything on the main website which gives instructions for installing fonts, but the result should look like e.g. the picture in this question.

@dROOOze Indeed, that seems to be the case. I found a set of fonts containing precomposed Bopomofo combinations in the Private Use Area, though using a different set of code points: https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/download/WSL_TPS_Font.htm

Ah, this might contain the download links on their site: https://2blog.ilc.edu.tw/3860/2012/06/06/台語注音軟體/ - unfortunately the links are dead. Nothing on web archive or any font literally named "台語新細明體" either, from a Google search.

I am using MS Explorer, below are the texts spaced with the symbol "" shown on my screen:

Use "copy and paste", the result is as shown below:
（5-5）黎明國小好名聲
Lê– bîng – kok – sió hó miâ – siann
黎明國小好名聲，
Hāu – tiúnn tsú – jīm tsìn phah – piànn
校長主任真拍拚，
The writing expresses the Hokkien dialect using Traditional Chinese characters. The symbol "" could be "Garbled characters (亂碼)" caused by the compatibility between the input/output software.
